# migrate site columns, content types and master pages/layouts

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Are there any examples how to migrate site columns, content types and master pages/ layouts via feature? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any feature, the only way i know is creating backups of the databse of the site, and restore it in another, where the structure is the same